# Как читать и использовать переменные из файла

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы

До этого момента я использовал для этого модуль `pathlib` код приклеплю ниже.
И поскольку он(`pathlib`) может читать до 10 переменных, у меня появилась надобность в его замене.

```
import pathlib
import threading
#File validation
file = pathlib.Path('Variables.txt')
if file.is_file():
    money, s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7, L, b1, pers = map(int, file.open().readlines())
else:
    d = money, s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, L, b1, pers = [0, 5, 1000, 10000, 50000, 150000, 500000, 1000000, 1, 20000, 0]
    file.write_text('\n'.join(map(str, d)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Модуль `pathlib` может читать сколько угодно переменных. В данном случае вы пытаетесь при записи файла запихнуть 11 значений в 10 переменных, поэтому Python выдаёт ошибку.
Если добавить ещё одну переменную, то всё работает

```
import pathlib
import threading
#File validation
file = pathlib.Path('Variables.txt')
if file.is_file():
    money, s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7, L, b1, pers = map(int, file.open().readlines())

else:
    d = money, s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7, L, b1, pers = [0, 5, 1000, 10000, 50000, 150000, 500000, 1000000, 1, 20000, 0]
    file.write_text('\n'.join(map(str, d)))
```